# Generic help defining the interface

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a set of API's for which I am creating a reactive version using project-reactor

My existing interface is something like

```
  Profile getProfile(String accessToken);

  Profile getProfileByEmail(String adminToken, String email);

  Token validateToken(String accessToken);
  ...
```

The project reactor variant will be

```
  Mono<Profile> getProfile(String accessToken);

  Mono<Profile> getProfileByEmail(String adminToken, String email);

  Mono<Token> validateToken(String accessToken);
  ...
```

Another variant will be

```
  CompletableFuture<Profile> getProfile(String accessToken);

  CompletableFuture<Profile> getProfileByEmail(String adminToken, String email);

  CompletableFuture<Token> validateToken(String accessToken);
  ...
```

I want to define a super interface using generics for these above API.

Any help on how to define the interface without having to deal with unchecked exceptions will be help.

Answer (score 2):

There's no sensible way to create a common interface for these three classes. (You could, but the return type would have to be `Object`, which probably doesn't make it too useful.) This is the case in "real-world" services too - [SqsClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sqs/SqsClient.html) and [SqsAsyncClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sqs/SqsAsyncClient.html) are just blocking / non-blocking clients for the same service, but none of the "operation" method definitions come from a common interface.

If you really *must* have all options available, and you may add others in the future, the most sensible thing to do here is probably to implement the *actual* service using `CompleteableFuture` and then implement the other services using that service. That probably gives you the most compatible option moving forward:

```
class BlockingProfileService {

    CompletableFutureProfileService service;

    public BlockingProfileService(CompletableFutureProfileService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    Profile getProfile(String accessToken) {
        return service.getProfile(accessToken).get();
    }

    //..etc..
```

and:

```
class ReactorProfileService {

    CompletableFutureProfileService service;

    public ReactorProfileService(CompletableFutureProfileService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    Mono<Profile> getProfile(String accessToken) {
        return Mono.fromFuture(service.getProfile(accessToken));
    }
```

You can of course use some other boilerplate so you don't need to pass in a `CompleteableFutureProfileService` directly, that can be created with the necessary parameters in the other service.

However, I fear you may be over-complicating things here. If you're just using reactor throughout (which means reactor must be a dependency already), then just stick with `Mono` - there's no need to mix `Mono` and `CompletableFuture`, and there's certainly no need to maintain a legacy blocking API (as that can trivially be obtained by blocking on any asynchronous library.)

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response and clarifications. Our eventual goal is to retire the blocking implementation but we are not there yet. The goal is to implement the synchronous API using the new reactive API as you suggested above. Unfortunately as of now we can't touch the current API's.

Since the API's are part of the library and not everyone will have reactor we need to support the native CompletableFutures as well.